# A class has 30 distinct students enrolled, is there a difference between the number of ways we can put them in a row of 30 and 2 rows of 15?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

So I have 30 distinct students. Conceptually, I understand that if I put them in a single row that there are 30! ways to do that (30 * 29 * 28 ... * 1). If I put them into two different rows of 15 students, is there a difference or is it also 30! different ways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is a row $A$ and a row $B$ (that is, if we distinguish between the rows), then it makes no difference, and so it would still be $30!$

But my guess is that the problem is asking you to not make a difference between the two rows. That is, if you switch the rows, it would be considered the same two rows, and hence the same distribution of students (the same 'solution' if you want). So in that case you should divide by $2$.

Comment: That's what I thought, but I wasn't sure. The question does distinguish between a front row and a back row, but the extra info about not making a difference between the rows makes sense. Thanks a lot!